# laravel uuid not showing in query

Tags: php, postgresql, laravel, eloquent, uuid

I've a postgres database table that uses uuid's as its primary key, via the **webpatser/laravel-uuid** package, and 'readable' web ids via **vinkla/hashids**.

When I query the database, if I **dd()** the response, I see the UUID in full, but if I simply **return**, I instead get an integer.

Presume I've overlooking something obvious, so:

**Migration**

```
$table->uuid('id');
$table->string('web_id');

$table->primary('id');
```

**Model**

```
public function store()
{
    $data = [
        'id' => Uuid::generate(4)->string,
        'web_id' => Hashids::encode(mt_rand(1,1000000)),
```

I'm assuming something happens when the data is cast to json, but I'm not sure where'd I'd begin to tackle this...

I also see the same behaviour in artisan tinker, fwiw:

```
 >>> $result = App\Model::firstOrFail() 
 => App\Model {#675
     id: "587bb487-881d-417e-8960-fbecaa3b270b",
     web_id: "Mxqv4LYP",
     created_at: "2016-01-25 15:52:25+00",
     updated_at: "2016-01-25 15:52:25+00",
    }

 >>> $result->id
 => 587
```

Comment: What is the type of your `id` field in database, and what is length?

Comment: I'm using postgres, and Postico simply reports it as type 'uuid', if that's of any help.

Comment: May be try to convert result to array `->toArray()` and make dd();

Comment: Thanks - so, in tinker,`$result` and `dd($result)` give `'id' => (uuid...)`, whereas `$result->toArray()` and `dd($result->toArray())` both give `'id' => (integer...)`

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Eloquent makes the assumption that the primary key (which is [named `id` by default](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.2/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php#L56)) is an integer, and it casts it to `int` by default in the [`getCasts`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.2/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php#L2821) method:

```
public function getCasts()
{
    if ($this->incrementing) {
        return array_merge([
            $this->getKeyName() => 'int',
        ], $this->casts);
    }
    return $this->casts;
}
```

This can be overwritten by specifying that the primary key is not auto incrementing by adding this to your model:

```
$incrementing = false;
```

Or by casting the `id` column to `string` in the `$casts` property of the model, like so:

```
protected $casts = [
    'id' => 'string'
]
```

As described in the [Eloquent: Attribute Casting](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-mutators#attribute-casting) documentation.

Comment: Aha! Thanks for the update - makes perfect sense now!

Comment: I've updated your answer for future readers to include the explanation on why the `id` was being automatically cast to `int`.

Comment: I've posted a second (simpler) solution in the answer that will also fix the problem, since it makes the condition in `getCasts` false, so it avoids the `id` being cast to `int` in the first place.

Comment: You can also override the model's `protected $keyType = 'string';` attribute.

Comment: The `$incrementing = false;` saved my day. Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

In laravel 8 I had to set

```
public $incrementing = false;
```

into the model.