# Laravel eloquent UUID in a pivot table

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, pivot, laravel-5.4

This question is like this one: **[laravel uuid not showing in query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34997767/laravel-uuid-not-showing-in-query)**. However, the difference in this question is about that table is a pivot table with `id` field uses UUID generated via MySQL trigger on insert.

I don't want to create another model for that pivot table to supply it with the solution regarded on the similar question's answer. So, is there any way to perform type casting of the pivot table from another model related to it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this might be what you want:

In your model that defines the BelongsToMany relationship add this property:

```
protected $casts = ['relationName.pivot.id' => 'string'];
```

**Update**

I guess we can make use of anonymous classes in `php7.0` here instead of creating a model class for the pivot:

*i didn't test this code so i don't know if it will work or not, this is just an idea*

```
public function activeStatuses()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('ModelName')
                ->using(class_basename(new class extends \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Pivot {
                    protected $casts = ['id' => 'string'];
                }));
}
```

Generally i would prefer to create model for the pivot table or simply use a [pivot class](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42272466/2353053)

Comment: I have tried `protected $casts = ['activeStatuses.pivot.id' => 'string'];` but it does not work.

Comment: Thank you, extended model with custom string `$primaryKey` and `$casts = ['customPrimaryField' => 'string']` worked flawless.

Comment: @RamyTamer Currently I used it but I have got an error about missing parameters for Pivot construct method `Type error: Too few arguments to function Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Pivot::__construct(), 0 passed`

Comment: What should I suppose to put in "'relationName" ?

Answer (score 2):

Since Laravel 9 you can pass the trait `HasUuids` to new instances:

```
    /**
     * @return BelongsToMany<\App\Models\ExampleModel>
     */
    public function tags(): BelongsToMany
    {
        return $this
            ->belongsToMany(\App\Models\ExampleModel::class)
            ->using(new class extends \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Pivot; {
                use \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Concerns\HasUuids;
            });
    }
```

An alternative is to create a pivot class and set this use statement there. However, this was excluded by the questioner.

Comment: Is this `PHP`? `...tags(): BelongsToMany...`? :)

Comment: Yes. This is a PHP method return type declaration. The return type is
```Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany```

Answer (score 0):

It works for me:

```
// use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Pivot;
return $this->belongsToMany(Vendor::class, 'vendors_has_geo_cities', 'city_id', 'vendor_id')
            ->using(new class extends Pivot {
                use UuidTrait;
            });
```

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;

trait UuidTrait
{
    public function initializeUuidTrait(): void
    {
        $this->setIncrementing(false);
        $this->setKeyType('string');
    }

    /**
     * The "booting" method of the model.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected static function bootUuidTrait()
    {
        self::creating(function (Model $model) {
            $model->setAttribute($model->getKeyName(), Str::orderedUuid());
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Indirect modification of overloaded element of App\\Models\\Vendor has no effect