# laravel-uuid UUID not filled on save()

Tags: php, laravel-5.4, uuid

Attempting to use this, but when saving no UUID is entered into the db.

Here is my setup:

**DB:**
Name: uuid char(36) utf8mb4_unicode_ci

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Cviebrock\EloquentSluggable\Sluggable;
use Emadadly\LaravelUuid\Uuids;

class Account extends Model
{
   use Uuids;

   protected $fillable = [
      'name', 'tname', 'short', 'uuid'
   ];

   protected $guarded = [
      'id'
   ];
```

**Controller:**

```
public function saveUUID(Account $account){
$example = new Account;

    $example->name = 'test';
    $example->short = 'FIVE';
    $example->industry_id = 1;
    $example->user_id = 1;
    $example->status_id = 36;
    $example->save();

return response()->json(['example' => $example]);
}
```

The uuid field is left null, and the response for $example does not include the uuid.

What am i missing or doing wrong?

Comment: can I see you Uuids trait

Comment: Does your `$fillable` array in `Account` has `uuid` field?

Comment: Try to checkout this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43240247/laravel-eloquent-uuid-in-a-pivot-table

Comment: @IvankaTodorova yes. Updated ques to show this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would personally create a UUID trait like the following.

```
<?php

use Ramsey\Uuid\Uuid;

trait HasUuid
{

protected static function bootHasUuid()
{
    /**
     * Attach to the 'creating' Model Event to provide a UUID
     * for the `uuid` field
     */
    static::creating(function ($model) {
        $columnName = static::getUuidColumn();

        $model->$columnName = Uuid::uuid4();
    });
}

/* Getters and Setters */


public function getUuidAttribute()
{
    $columnName = static::getUuidColumn();

    return $this->attributes[$columnName];
}

protected static function getUuidColumn()
{
    if (isset(static::$uuidColumn)) {
        return static::$uuidColumn;
    }
    return 'uuid';
}
```

Now in you model you can include HasUuid trait

```
<?php

class Model {
use HasUuid
//.....
}
```

FYI if your uuid field is called something else in you class model you can declare the filed like so `static $uuidColumn = 'user_uuid':`.

Trait will handle the rest

Comment: That worked very nicely, thank you! Even works with the save() method.

Comment: @SeánMcCabe awesome. If you check `bootHasUuid` method you can see something like ` static::creating`. this means every-time a model tries to save something this method will trigger and the `uuid` is created.

Answer (score -1):

Add to the modal:

```
protected $fillable = array('*');

protected $guarded = ['id'];
```

Comment: no effect. Updated question to show those fields as they stood and with your guarded addition